# How to use rangeDataMode correctly in NSDatePicker?

Tags: swift, macos, nsdatepicker

In a Mac OS X app, I try to set the `datePickerMode` to use `rangeDataMode` because I do want to pick up a range of dates (a start date & an end date).

```
let datePicker = NSDatePicker()
datePicker.datePickerMode = .rangeDateMode
```

However, the `NSDatePicker` still works like `singleDateMode`. I can only specify one date in that `NSDatePicker`.

How to use `rangeDataMode` correctly?

Comment: Did you add the date picker in a storyboard or XIB or do you add the date picker in code?

Comment: @Willeke in code

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, `.rangeDateMode` only seems to have an effect when `datePickerStyle` is set to `.clockAndCalendarDatePickerStyle`, since as you have noticed, the default "stepper" style doesn't have any obvious UI for selecting a range rather than an individual date. Try running the date picker in calendar style, and you should be able to select ranges.